# Slow MySQL query in Laravel is fast elsewhere

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, eloquent

I'm using Eloquent in a Laravel 4.2 application. One of my controller comes back with a view after about 6000ms, which is way too long. It processes data from a table called `responses`. It works pretty ok with a couple of thousand rows, but when I'm over 30000 it starts getting really slow.

Here's the weird part. 
If I check my `DB::getQueryLog();` I can see this query:

```
[1] => Array
        (
            [query] => select * from `response` where `survey_id` = ? and `question_id` = ? and `resp_group` in (?, ?)
            [bindings] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 48
                    [1] => 25
                    [2] => a
                    [3] => b
                )

            [time] => 11
        )
```

which I assume would result in this actual query:

```
select * from `response` 
where `survey_id` = 48 
and `question_id` = 25 
and `resp_group` in ('a', 'b');
```

As you can see the time is pretty high there. And the log tells me I run queries like this about 40 times with time between 7 and 11.

But if I run the same query in HediSQL I get 0,000 sec and 0.0010 in PHPMyAdmin.  I have to run 20 of them to get 0,015 seconds.

Explain gives this:

```
    select_type: SIMPLE
    table: response
    possible_keys: 
      question_id_4, 
      resp_group_survey_id, 
      survey_id, 
      resp_group_question_id_survey_id
    key: question_id_4
    key_len: 8
    ref: const,const
    rows: 949
    Extra: Using where
```

So there are indexes. How come the same query is so slow when Eloquent performs it and so much faster when I run it directly on the MySQL Server?

(I'm running on my Local WAMP server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The time in **DB::getQueryLog()** is reported in milliseconds so it is more or less the same to what PHPMyAdmin reports.

The reason why controller method takes 6 seconds to execute is probably related to the amount of data (30000 rows) that Eloquent needs to process after it fetches the data from the database.

If you want to make that faster use DB class instead.

```
DB::table('response')
->whereSurveyId($survey_id)
->whereQuestionId($question_id)
->whereIn('resp_group', $groups)
->get();
```

It might be also helpful to provide a list of required columns to **get()** so that you fetch less data from the database.

Comment: The amount of rows I get doesn't affect the speed. if I get 17000 rows or 1000 it takes the same time. The problem is that it gets slower as the table grows - even though I have indexed every single thinkable column combination.

Comment: As I wrote above, what DB::getQueryLog() says is that the query took 11 milliseconds to execute, so it's not the query that makes the controler slow.

Comment: Thank you! Running the query like that actually cut the time down from >6000ms to about 900ms. How come DB class is som much faster? Is there really any point in using Eloquent for fetching unless it's only a single  entity?

Comment: Eloquent objects make it very easy to operate on underlying data and the overhead of building the objects is low, so it's usually a better choice as long as you don't fetch too many objects or do not process the objects heavily. When you fetch a lot of data then time needed to turn plain data into objects increases, but what adds even more overhead are Eloquent's magic getters and setters. Every time you do "$model->attributeName" there is a chain of methods that are executed just to give you the value of "attribute".

Comment: Oh, I see. Using the DB object then gives you a lot less overhead when accessing the attributes? I'm surprised that I could basically just keep my eloquent code intact and only change the query.

Comment: To add to @jedrzej.kurylo's answer, the DB object gives you a plain array, or object depending on your configured fetch style. You can see this in `database.php` under `fetch`, it will either be `PDO::FETCH_OBJ` or `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC`. I'm guessing that yours is probably set to `PDO::FETCH_OBJ` which makes the `DB` return objects of type `stdClass` that actually have the attributes you're trying to access. There is no dynamic accessing of the attributes there. The dynamic accessing happens on objects that extend the `Model` class.